# Tkinter button messing up the GUI?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I'm making a simple login thing with tkinter (Python 2.7).

And I've been trying to debug this problem and I figured out what's causing it.

Basically the issues is when I remove the Tkinter button from the GUI it launches perfectly well. But, when I add it back I don't even see the GUI or anything. Here's my code :

```
    print ("Loading...")
    from Tkinter import *
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Login Box")
    root.geometry("350x100")
    L1 = Label(root, text = "Username :").grid(row=0)
    L2 = Label(root, text = "Password : ").grid(row=1)
    Username = Entry(root).grid(row=0, column = 1)
    Password = Entry(root).grid(row = 1, column = 1)
    LoginButton = Button(root, text = "Login & Show Data!", command=Confirm) #Run confirm code.
    LoginButton.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

So if I run that I don't see it. But, removing the "LogingButton" it works then.

Any help is appreciated,
Thank you.

Comment: You cannot mix the `.pack()` and `.grid()` geometry managers in a single container widget.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: `_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager pack inside . which already has slaves managed by grid`. In other words change `LoginButton.pack()` to `LoginButton.grid()`.

Comment: Oooh! Okay got it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't use both pack() and grid(). When I run your program I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ButtonAddition.py", line 10, in <module>
    LoginButton.pack()
  File "/home/eshita/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2140, in pack_configure
    + self._options(cnf, kw))
_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager pack inside . which already has slaves managed by grid
```

So,

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Login Box")
root.geometry("350x100")
L1 = Label(root, text = "Username :").grid(row=0)
L2 = Label(root, text = "Password : ").grid(row=1)
Username = Entry(root).grid(row=0, column = 1)
Password = Entry(root).grid(row = 1, column = 1)
LoginButton = Button(root, text = "Login & Show Data!", command=Confirm) #Run confirm code.
LoginButton.grid()          # Change the pack() to grid()
root.mainloop()
```

The above changes will remove the error. Hope this helps.